# Antiderivative function of $\arccos(1/x)/\sqrt{x^2-a}$

Tags: integration

I want to compute analytically the antiderivative (or primitive) of the function:

$$f(x)=\frac{\arccos(1/x)}{\sqrt{x^2-a}}$$ 
Where $a$ is a real constant.

I tried many substitutions but it doesn't work. I need an analytical solution.

Thank you for any possible help.

Comment: A rapid hint would involve seeing the above integral as: $$\int\frac{1/\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{(x/\sqrt{a})^2-1}}\cdot\mathrm{arccos}(1/x)\, \mathrm{d} x$$ then knowing that $\mathrm{arccosh}^\prime(\square)=\square^\prime/\sqrt{\square^2-1}$ (where $\square$ is any $C^{1}$, $\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ function) suggests successive integration by parts

Comment: It would be great if you develop more your method. itried what you suggest but i failed.

Comment: I noticed the method for my hint by intuition, as I've not checked it, so I'll come up with an answer knowing that I may have had the wrong problem's attack pattern.

Comment: Okeye, i will wait then for a possible solution from you. Thank's

Comment: After many trials, [Wolfram for $a=1$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arccos%281%2Fx%29%2F%28sqrt%28x^2-1%29%29) and [Wolfram for $a$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+arccos%281%2Fx%29%2F%28sqrt%28x^2-a%29%29) confirmed my primary worry: this integral is not elementary or expressible in terms of common funcions.